# Android FAB behaviour with listview for custom layout

Tags: android, listview, material-design

I would like to achieve behaviour similar to this example

[image]

but without toolbar move and for custom view not for a FAB. So, firstly i would like to see layout similar to https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html (it can be simple LinearLayout placed on bottom of the screen with some child views) which hides when i start scroll down listview and appears when i scroll up a little. Have digged deep in web but found nothing what really works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to extend [default FAB behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html), in order to keep FAB behavior when `Snackbar` is shown. Otherwise you will see it not translating upwards when `Snackbar` pops up.

React on vertical scrolling only:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent,
        View child, View target, View target,int scrollAxes) {
    return (scrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0;
}
```

Once you have vertical nested scrolling accumulate how much has been scrolled. Start translating the FAB when you have scrolled as much as FAB height:

```
    Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
         if (dy > 0 && mTotalDy < 0 || dy < 0 && mTotalDy > 0) {
             mTotalDy = 0;
         }

         mTotalDy += dy;
         if ( mTotalDy > child.getHeight() 
                && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
             //translate to it's height, offscreen, set visbility to gone at end of translation animation
        } else if (mTotalDy < 0 
                && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            //translate to 0 set visbility to visible at end of translation animation
        }

}
```

When `mTotalDy` is greater than FAB height we have scrolling down, when the `mTotalDy` we are scrolling up.

You should also take care of nested flinging in `onNestedPreFling()` method. Hide the FAB when the `velocityY < 0` and show it when `velocityY > 0`, all these conditions only when `Math.abs(velocityY) > Math.abs(velocityX)`. In other words, only when there is vertical flinging.

Comment: Nice answer. I like this solution, got to it before me :D

Comment: Sounds really nice, I will test that soon, thank you :)

Comment: Quick Question, My bottombar parent is LinearLayout , So LinearLayout need to extends default FAB behavior ?