# Scrolling RecyclerView behind a AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to achieve an effect like the videos in the "behavior section" at this [URL](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior) ( Google Design official site ). It's the same effect of Google Photo, I guess, with a search bar on the top of the RecyclerView that disappear/appear on scrolling up/down

I don't know how to get it, I started with [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html), but I can't get the RecyclerView visible behind the AppBarLayout, it always remains white, covering the RecyclerView as show below ( result and code [edit: added image with layout layers] ).

Or it's a custom [CoordinatorLayout.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) ?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated, thank you

[image: result]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Sample layout

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the solid white border that overlaps the RecyclerView when scrolling down?

Comment: Yes, just that view.  I'm trying to get the same effect as indicated in the google documentation linked in the question

Comment: Try removing the margins' properties on SearchView, and adding similar paddings' properties on AppBarLayout.

Comment: It doesnt work, but I have more clear the problem. It's "something" under the AppBar and over the RW ( still not resolved, i will edit the question soon ), thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely a custom [CoordinatorLayout.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html).
After some searches and readings ( [most important](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#.oy37igemb), [some inspirations](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/bottomnavigationview-missing-pearls-eaa950f9ad4e#.5p32e477g), [more inspirations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715732/how-to-scroll-up-down-of-bottom-bar-on-scrolling-of-recyclerview), and [the foundamentals](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#custom-behaviors) ), I got what I wanted with the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/grid_spacing_header"/>

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/searchbar_top"
        app:layout_behavior=".SearchBarBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

with my own SearchBarBehavior that extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior
[code still incomplete]

Comment: following for news

Comment: I see this is 4 years old now, but did you ever solve the custom behavior script?

Comment: I gave up. It was a side project

Answer (score 0):

try to set CoordinatorLayout also transparent

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

Comment: It doesnt work, but I have more clear the problem. It's "something" under the AppBar and over the RW ( still not resolved, i will edit the question soon ), thank you