# Make Toolbar/Bottombar show programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

How to do the Toolbar and Bottom bar behave like the image in this link in Android?

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/102792/screenshots/2792071/toc.gif
source: https://dribbble.com/shots/2792071-Table-of-Contents-Juggernaut

Tried to upload the image but got error

Comment: Someone named Krishan have a good solution for you from another similar question.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34870372/4375046)

Comment: Thank you @gal-yedidovich, but it seems related to scroll. I do not want to make it work with scroll. I just want to slide top and bottom out/in screen as the user clicks content

Comment: I see, then you should implement the same, `onShow` & `onHide` methods with an `onClick` event