# Bottom navigation overlapping recycler view contents in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am using bottom navigation view and displaying three tabs,In one of the tab i have added recycler view, but the contents are overlapped by bottom navigation.Not able to scroll recycler view.Is there any way that i can  hide the bottom navigation when i scroll item on recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:sv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".activity.patient.PatientsActivity">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/asd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <co.moonmonkeylabs.realmrecyclerview.RealmRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/appointmentsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:rrvEmptyLayoutId="@layout/empty_view"
                app:rrvLayoutType="LinearLayout"
                app:rrvSwipeToDelete="true" />

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:itemBackground="@color/white"
                app:layout_behavior=".BottomNavigationBehavior"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHDq8.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First i think you could add an:

> android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"

To the Recyclerview

For the Scrolling part i would suggest looking for a ScrollingBehaviour 
like in this question:
[How to scroll up/down of bottom bar on scrolling of RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715732/how-to-scroll-up-down-of-bottom-bar-on-scrolling-of-recyclerview)

Comment: it was simple :)

Comment: android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" this made the trick

Answer (score 1):

add NestedScrollView just before RecyclerView this may work like above

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <co.moonmonkeylabs.realmrecyclerview.RealmRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/appointmentsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:rrvEmptyLayoutId="@layout/empty_view"
                app:rrvLayoutType="LinearLayout"
                app:rrvSwipeToDelete="true" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```